# Xamarin : Ambiguity Errors while building solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have cloned my Xamarin project from github, and I get many ambiguity errors while building the solution.

Few of them are -

```
Ambiguity between 'Settings.AppSettings' and 'Settings.AppSettings' 
Ambiguity between 'Settings.Settingskey' and 'Settings.Settingskey'     
Ambiguity between 'Settings.SettingsDefault' and 'Settings.SettingsDefault'
```

What I have tried-

1. Clean, and rebuild solution. Restart visual studio several times
2. Remove .vs folder, and rebuild
3. **dotnet restart** from cmd.
4. Manually update nuget packages.

None of these seem to work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information about Settings class it's difficult to give an answer, however, I suspect that as you have cloned your project from another source, its possible that you may have renamed it and now your Settings class appears in more than one namespace.